# Множество VM для схожих моделей

Tags: c#, ооп, mvvm, архитектура, solid

Столкнулся с проблемой при проектировании приложения, используя WPF и паттерн MVVM.

Модель представляет из себя один компонент (Допустим, Company)

```
class Company
{
    private string _Name;
    public ObservableCollection<Manager> Managers {get; set;}
    public ObservableCollection<Director> Directors {get; set;}
    public ObservableCollection<Tester> Testers {get; set;}
}
```

Для этой модели есть свой VM и View. Детали вроде InotifyPropertyChanged я опущу, будем считать, они реализованы в базовом классе ViewModel, объекты Command и Mediator соответствуют реализации классических паттернов

```
class CompanyViewModel: ViewModel
{
   private Company _Company;

   public ICommand AddManagerCommand { get; }
   public ICommand AddTesterCommand { get; }
   public ICommand AddDirectorCommand { get; }

   public CompanyViewModel()
   {
      _Company = new Company();
      AddManagerCommand = new Command(OnAddManagerExecuted);
      AddTesterCommand = new Command(OnAddTesterExecuted);
      AddDirectorCommand = new Command(OnAddDirectorExecuted);

      Mediator.Register("GetManager", OnGetManager);
      ...
     ...

   }

    private void OnGetManager(object obj)
    {
        _Company.Managers.Add((Employee)obj);
    }
}
```

внутри этой модели, есть множество объектов, которые она в себя включает. По аналогии с компанией их можно представить как работников Manager, Director, Tester и все они наследуются от класс Employee.

```
class Employee
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
class Manager : Employee
{
    public string Age {get; set;}
    public string Sex {get; set;}
}
class Director : Employee
{
    public string Age {get; set;}
    public string Education {get; set;}
}
...
```

Для редактирования каждого типа работников, предусмотренно свое представление и своя VM.

```
class ManagerViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public Command SaveCommand {get; private set;}

    public ManagerViewModel()
    {
        SaveCommand = new Command(OnSaveCommandExecuted)
    }

    private void OnSaveCommandExecuted(object window)
    {
        Mediator.NotifyColleggues("GetManager", new Manager())
    }
}
```

В результате, с таким подходом, я имею множество VM и view для каждого типа сотрудников и для каждого из них своя ObservableCollection в модели Company.

Таким образом, при добавлении нового типа сотрудников я вынужден унаследовать от Employee новый класс, создать новую VM, новый View, зарегистрировать в Mediator новое сообщение, чтобы оповестить VM Сompany о добавлении нового элемента в ObservableCollection из View нового типа сотрудника и добавить новую Command в VM Company для вызова Окна редактирования сотрудника. Эта архитектура кажется мне ужасно регидной и я хотел бы узнать, какое решение может помочь мне увеличить масштабируемость системы, возможно какое-то специфическое использование Фасада для моделей или Интерфейсов?

Comment: А можете весь этот текст разделить на абзацы и добавить код (примеры)? Что бы можно было получше понять то, что вы хотите и что имеете. Ибо я читаю и что то...

Comment: Благодарю за комментарий, добавил кусочки воображаемого кода, для иллюстрации написанного, надеюсь, стало понятнее.

Comment: А чем вам простой интерфейс не подошел? Переделываете допустим `class Employee` в `interface IEmployee`. Тогда к примеру можно сделать коллекцию с этим интерфейсом, скажем: `public ObservableCollection<IEmployee> Workers` и в нее добавлять всех менеджеров и директоров, которые реализовывают этот интерфейс. В View это все можно обыграть скажем через `DataTemplate`, у которого можно задать отдельный вид под определенный тип данных.

Comment: Такое как у вас наследование не нужно потому, что `Manager, Director, Tester` - это фактически роли или набор доп. свойств к классу `Employee`. Используйте интерфейсы.

Comment: Спасибо, воспользуюсь советом. Учитывая, что для редактирования объекта создается отдельный View использовал ControlTemplate и действительно убрал лишнее дублирование и сократил объем кода и связанность элементов.